# UIView bounds.size.height returns 0.0 iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have an extension to `UIView` which tries to calculate the `bounds.size` and then tries to get `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. This is used to render a blurred `view` of the current screen shot after a set time interval.

The problem is the **UIView bounds.size.height** **sometime returns 0.0** which in turn results in `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` being `nil`.

Any reason why the `bounds.size`.height is `0.0` sometimes?

`

```
extension UIView 
{
  func blurredImage() -> UIImage? 
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
   ...
  }
}
```

`

Comment: When do you call blurredImage ?? If the image is not yet rendered on screen bounds is supposed to be zero :)

Comment: you should call this in `func viewDidLayoutSubviews` for `UIViewController` or `override func layoutSubviews` for `UIView's`